# Is there any method to click on a flatpickr date automatically using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I tried to auto-click on below calendar created with flatpickr using jQuery but it's not working, Any method to do that?

**Image:** [Screenshot of Calander.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnmjz.png)

```
<span class="flatpickr-day click-this" aria-label="October 9, 2022" tabindex="-1">9</span>
```

```js
jQuery (function($) { 
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".click-this").trigger("click") 
  }) 
})
```

Can someone help me to click automatically on the date on calendar with click-this class?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from the context of your question that you're trying to set the default date displayed in the flatpickr control, then you don't need to auto-click anything. You can simply set the `defaultDate` property in the settings object you provide when instantiating the library:

```js
const today = new Date();
const tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);

$("#date").flatpickr({
  inline: true,
  defaultDate: tomorrow
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.13/flatpickr.min.js" integrity="sha512-K/oyQtMXpxI4+K0W7H25UopjM8pzq0yrVdFdG21Fh5dBe91I40pDd9A4lzNlHPHBIP2cwZuoxaUSX0GJSObvGA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.13/flatpickr.min.css" integrity="sha512-MQXduO8IQnJVq1qmySpN87QQkiR1bZHtorbJBD0tzy7/0U9+YIC93QWHeGTEoojMVHWWNkoCp8V6OzVSYrX0oQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<input type="text" id="date" />
```

More details on the settings available when using flatpickr can be found in the documentation: https://flatpickr.js.org/options/

Comment: Need to auto submit it? How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by auto-submit? Your question isn't clear